# What web server does ASP.NET MVC 5+ use on non-Windows platforms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cross-platform

I am confused about the cross-platform aspects of ASP.NET 5 and beyond as it relates to web applications.

If I do not have IIS on Linux or Mac OSX, what container do I use to run ASP.NET (for web)?

I saw an example using cloud based, but what if I want everything hosted in-house?

Comment: [Have a look here](http://graemechristie.github.io/graemechristie/blog/2014/05/26/asp-dot-net-vnext-on-osx-and-linux/)

Comment: @StuartLC I thought mono was not something guaranteed to be maintained.  Isn't Microsoft doing something that is completely a Microsoft product that is cross platform?

Answer (score 0):

Asp.net as it is today will not run outside windows, however with vnext due later this year (in beta now) it will. Perhaps take a look at the beta at asp.net/vnext

Answer (score 0):

Try with kestrel
https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer

Kestrel is a web server based on libuv  like node.js